# C# formatting currency given currency code (like USD / GBP / FRF)

Tags: c#, formatting, globalization, currency

I am integrating with a database which returns currencies (`System.Decimal`) and currency codes. The currency codes are strings like `"USD"`, `"GBP"`, and even `"FRF"`.

Is there something built-in to mscorlib which can help me format these currencies? I first thought about setting up a mapping between database currency code and `CultureInfo`, but I don't know what to do about FRF because if I use `"fr-FR"`, it would format as euros instead of francs.

The full list of currency symbols we must support is:

```
FRF
CHF
NZD
IN2
SAR
SEK
EUR
MXP
DKK
GBP
AUD
IN1
AED
CAD
NOK
INR
USD
PLN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [replace the default currency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688126.aspx#ete) and still make use of the framework...

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
public class EuroLocalSample
{
   public static void Main()
   { 
     // Create a CultureInfo object for French in France.
     CultureInfo FrCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
     // Set the CurrentCulture to fr-FR.
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = FrCulture;
    // Clone the NumberFormatInfo object and create
    // a new object for the local currency of France.
    NumberFormatInfo LocalFormat =
    (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
    // Replace the default currency symbol with the local
    // currency symbol.
    LocalFormat.CurrencySymbol = "F";

    int i = 100;

    // Display i formatted as the local currency.
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", LocalFormat));
    // Display i formatted as the default currency.
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("c", NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo));
   }
}
```

Comment: Why is it safe to assume that merely replacing the currency symbol would yield an accurate formatting?

Comment: @tenfour Based on the docs I would gather that while the euro became the new currency in 1999 the formatting of the value to a string representation did not. So 100 displayed as euro or franc would only be different as defined by the trailing type of currency.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. But since I want the `NumberFormatInfo` to be *locked*, unchanged by windows update, I basically just serialized a map of existing `NumberFormatInfo` objects into XML, and edited the XML manually for things like FRF. Now we use this XML to define the formatting.

Comment: this solution doesn't display currency symbols.  it merely displays whatever string you put in the .CurrencySymbol field.  if I use "XYZ" it will just display "100 XYZ" and for USD it doesn't display "$100"

Answer (score 4):

> I first thought about setting up a mapping between database currency code and CultureInfo, but I don't know what to do about FRF because if I use "fr-FR", it would format as euros instead of francs.

I would take this approach, but make a custom `IFormatProvider` for FRF that does the formatting you choose.  This is as easy as constructing a [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) properly.

Comment: I think that they all need to be custom. Currencies in database records are relevant for a culture *at a specific point in time*, whereas `new CultureInfo(...)` only represents "now". Thus relying on *any* built-in cultures could mean currency symbols inadvertently change as the result of a Windows Update. Does this sound right?

Comment: @tenfour: Depends on what you're trying to do here.  If you want this to be updatable, then they don't have to be custom.  If you want this fixed, then you could use all custom verisons.  It's pretty easy to generate a NumberFormatInfo, though, so if you want to have complete control, making a set of custom ones in a dictionary would be a couple hours work, tops...

Answer (score 3):

That's a pretty small list. I'd just setup the mappings manually.