# Format Currency string in c# without currency code

Tags: c#

I am trying to format a double to currency string in c#

normally, I would use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
class Demo {
   static void Main() {
      double value = 234.66;
      Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
      Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C3", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
   }
}
```

issue:
The first format prepends an unwanted special caracter: `¤234.66`
the later one pepends a dollar sign: `$234.660`

for normal usecases, I could use several culture infos such as in [C# formatting currency given currency code (like USD / GBP / FRF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006546/c-sharp-formatting-currency-given-currency-code-like-usd-gbp-frf)

unfortunately, Crypto currencies are not supported as far as I know of. So I either look for no currency symbol at all (adding it later to the string) or for a custom currency symbol.
[image]

What was quite close was to use `balance.ToString("0.##")` but in case of `104.10` it would make `104.1` out of it..

Comment: And what happens with _0.00_?

Comment: `value.ToString("N2")`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#fixed-point-format-specifier-f

Answer (score 3):

```
var clone = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
clone.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
var currency = 104.67m;
var stringCurrency = currency.ToString("C", clone);
```

Comment: The Bitcoin symbol is Unicode code point: U+20BF  (`"\u20BF"`) - (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol).  Though I suspect there isn't very much in the way of font support yet.

Answer (score 0):

thanks! it's work

```
var formatMoney = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("vi-VN");
@String.Format(formatMoney, "{0:c}", @item.TotalPaid)
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34587794)